# Exception related to relative paths

Tags: c#, exception, directory

I am working on a C# sharp console application. I ran into the following error related to relative paths tried changing the debug settings from anyCPU to x86 as well, but that didn't work. Can someone point me in the right direction. Thanks

```
public static void ReadOrders(string pOrderDirectory)
        {
            // This exception is already thrown by <code>Directory.GetFiles()</code> but caught earlier here to allow 
            // the option of throwing an app-specific exception
            if (!Directory.Exists(pOrderDirectory))
            {
                throw new DirectoryNotFoundException("Unable to find input directory for orders: " + pOrderDirectory); //ran into the exception here.
            }

            // Process the list of files found in the directory.
            string[] oOrderFilenames = Directory.GetFiles(pOrderDirectory, SalesTaxHelper.GetConfigurationValue(CONFIG_KEY_FILE_SEARCH_PATTERN));

            if (oOrderFilenames.Length < 1)
            {
                throw new IOException("No orders found in input directory");
            }

            foreach (var oOrderFile in oOrderFilenames)
            {
                var oOrderProcessor = new Order();

                var oOrderLineItems = File.ReadAllLines(oOrderFile);
                foreach (var oLineItem in oOrderLineItems)
                {
                    oOrderProcessor.AddLineItem(oLineItem);
                }

                Console.WriteLine(oOrderProcessor.PrintInvoice());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("======================================");
            Console.WriteLine("PROCESSED ALL INPUT FILES IN DIRECTORY");
        }
```

> Exception: Unable to find input directory for orders:

Thanks,
Hari

Comment: Could be to do with privileges and having access to the location?

Comment: Does the directory exist?  What is the value of `pOrderDirectory` passed to the function?

Comment: The value to pOrderDirectory has to be populated with an input folder with 3 text files and currently it is not reading them

Comment: @Hari but what does `pOrderDirectory` actually look like?  Is it a fully qualified, valid path, e.g. "C:\users\hari\input\folder?" ...or "/stuff/here/" or something entirely different?  The exception is telling you it can't find the path you specified.  Make sure the path you specified is the correct format for the function.

Comment: I expect it to look like "/input" but, it is not getting populated with anything

Comment: Well then your problem is not here but where you try to populate your path.

Comment: @CNuts: I am new to working with Directories, can you please point me to an example of working with this. Thanks

Comment: Can you show us where you try to find the value you put in `pOrderDirectory`?

Comment: I have added it in the root folder inside the project and named it input. This folder has txt files with data like: 1 book at 12.49
1 music CD at 14.99
1 chocolate bar at 0.85. Not sure if this helps. This code is not written by me sorry please let me know if you need anything else

Comment: okay so make sure your folder named exactly `input` is placed in the bin > Debug folder of your project and if you set `pOrderDirectory = "input"` it should find the folder.

Comment: @CNuts: Thanks that did the trick!!

Comment: okay :) ill post it as an answer so you can close this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so make sure your folder named exactly input is placed in the bin > Debug folder of your project and if you set

```
pOrderDirectory = "input"
```

it should find the folder. The reason it will find the folder is because you're building in Debug mode so when you specify a path with just a simple string like I did it will be the default location where it will go search for the folder.

**Note that it won't find your folder if you change to Release because your folder is in Debug.**

Comment: Really should have an else so if directory doesn't exist you don't get exceptions : if (!Directory.Exists(pOrderDirectory))
            {
                throw new DirectoryNotFoundException("Unable to find input directory for orders: " + pOrderDirectory); //ran into the exception here.
            } else { rest of code}

Comment: Well the rest of his code uses that folder to function so if it didn't find it it should probably not continue.